# Using a local variable in the from statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, local-variables

I have a database where each table is named by standard conventions.
I am building a SQL script to run periodically on various sets of similarly named tables.

I would like to declare a local variable that contains common part of table names between the tables and use that variable to fill in a part of the table name in `FROM` statement of my `SELECT` statements.

How could I abstract this to run on a table where `1234` is substituted out for the value of a local variable?

```
Select count(*) From [Database].[dbo].[Table_1234]
```

This obviously doesn't work:

```
Select count(*) From [Database].[dbo].['Table_'+@variable]
```

Is there a way to use local variables as table names in select statements or a way around this?

Comment: The best way is to use "Dynamic SQL"

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** This *looks* like SQL Server to me, but the question was not tagged as such.

You can use the EXEC function:

```
EXEC('Select count(*) From [Database].[dbo].[Table_' + @variable + ']')
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ef1d/3

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how to get around the dynamic SQL. But I would recommend minimizing it by using synonyms (assuming you will be running multiple/complex queries instead of a simple row count):

```
DECLARE @var NVARCHAR(8)

SET @var = '1234'

EXEC('create synonym synTable1 for Table1_' + @var)
EXEC('create synonym synTable2 for Table2_' + @var)
EXEC('create synonym synTable3 for Table3_' + @var)

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM synTable1
...

DROP SYNONYM synTable1
DROP SYNONYM synTable2
DROP SYNONYM synTable3
```